# How Can I affect a QVariantMap from another QVariantMap?

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

Hello I'm developping a Blackberry 10 app. using the momentics IDE (BB Native SDK)

This error below is really stupid. But for lack of documentations, I can not find a solution for it. Can anyone please guid me on this .

```
QVariantMap m_applicationConfig;


void AppConfiguration::setApplicationConfig(QVariantMap argAppConfigParams) {
    m_applicationConfig = argAppConfigParams;
}
```

When I try to execute the function, it crush when it try to affect a QVariantMap from another QVariantMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first try to change function signature, like this:

```
void AppConfiguration::setApplicationConfig(const QVariantMap &argAppConfigParams) {
    m_applicationConfig = argAppConfigParams;
}
```

Then could you show code samples where you initialize m_applicationConfig and fill out the passed argument?

Comment: Actually, for the initialisation of **"m_applicationConfig "**, I just create the attribute in the **"xxx.h"** and I affect it with the value of the passed argument like mentined with the code.

Comment: OK, try to use debug output:
qDebug() << m_appConfig.size() << m_appConfig.keys();
qDebug() << argAppConfig.size() << argAppConfig.keys();
Run it in debug mode. Try to output any other params of QMap. If it doesn`t help you could try copy one map to another in loop with QMap::insert.